# `setxkbmap` doesn't alter modifier map

Tags: x11, xmodmap

I'm able to successfully update my keymap using this:

```
/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:swapcaps"
```

This doesn't seem to change my modifier map.

```
[OP@localhost ~]$ xmodmap
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x25)
control     Control_L (0x42),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

However, everything seems to work. My question is: **why doesn't this
change the modifier map, and if it works, what is the modifier map for?**

Comment: Can you confirm that not even any keycodes in parenthesis are changed?

Comment: The keycodes change. I think I understand, then. The modifier map binds a modifier to a list of keysyms. `setxkbmap` changes keycode -> keysym mappings, which is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modifier map doesn't change because there is nothing to change ;)

What happened is, `xkb` attribued a <kbd>Control_L</kbd> keysym to the keycode 66 where the keysym <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> was.

<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> keysym is still a Caps Lock modifier, even if it is not anymore affected to any keycode.

<kbd>Control_L</kbd> keysym was already in the Modmap, it doesn't need to be added.

In fact you may want to add another option : `shift:both_capslock` which will activate/desactivate <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> when you press both shift.
And because CapsLock was not removed from the Modmap, it will still work.

Now, for what is this modmap? There are others modifiers to think about :

⮱ <kbd>ISO_Level5_shift</kbd> is for polyglots, unicodes symbols, extending your keyboard with «EIGTH_LEVEL» keys.

⮱ <kbd>ISO_Prev_Group</kbd> is for multiple groups.

⮱ <kbd>Hyper</kbd> is popular for `Emacs` users.

... And so on, `xkb` come with many variant of each modifiers (shift, latch, lock), but beware these features aren't all compatible with `Xmodmap`.

Anyway Bravo for using `setxkbmap`, there is more inside than most users know.

`man Xkeyboard-config`

Notice you can use `localectl` to permanently apply your changes with the same options (take care of the slight semantics change tought).